# Fatal error in symfony2 AppKernel finding kernel class

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I am using symfony2. The code in my AppKernel looks like as follows:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle()
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new My\BookBundle\MyBookBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }
```

Now my code for one of the unit tests under Bookbundle looks like:

```
namespace My\BookBundle\Tests\Controller;

use My\BookBundle\Services\TestHelper;
use My\BookBundle\Tests\BaseTest;

class WriterControllerTest extends BaseTest
{
    /**
     * @var TestHelper
     */
    protected $testHelper;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->testHelper = $this->get('test_helper');
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->testHelper->setupTestData();
    }
```

Previously it was running the application and the test pretty smoothly. Then I was adding lots of functionality codes (such as controller, repository function, etc.). Now when I was trying to backup the codes by writing tests I am having the following error in the command prompt:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel' not found in /var/www/Symfony/app/AppKernel.php on line 7
```

Where the line 7 refers to the declaration of the AppKernel class as you can see in the above mentioned code.

I am confused and I am unable to find the reason behind the sudden breaking in code.

Can you please help?

Comment: Where do you have your autoload defined? Where are you loading it?

Comment: a unit tests that uses the appkernel...?

Comment: Did you maybe forget to install vendors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To @ONe: I have my autoload defined in app folder

To @Wouter J: Unit test is not using appkernel - it is only the error that is showing

To @Ramon Kleiss: I have the vendors installed and uninstalled and then reinstalled. Nothing changed.

I couldn't figured out what is the reason behind but I was able to solve the problem. It was related to permission change of the Test and Vendor folders. As I have mentioned that it was running earlier -- for some unknown reason permission for my bundles test folder and vendor folder was changed so it couldn't accessed proper files. I removed my installation and took fresh clone from repository and installed the project as per rules and everything was fine. I figured out the difference of the old and latest project filesystem and found that only permission was the difference.

Thanks for answering though.